# access button on fragment visual studio xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have button on axml file and it called from fragment. How can i use the button, for example i want to have onclick command from button with id "cobaButton". I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin for developing Android app.

This is my activity

```
public class MenuUtama : Activity
{
    private DrawerLayout _drawer;
    private MyActionBarDrawerToggle _drawerToggle;
    private ListView _drawerList;

    private string _drawerTitle;
    private string _title;
    private string[] _planetTitles;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MenuUtama);



            _title = _drawerTitle = Title;
        _planetTitles = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.PlanetsArray);
        _drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        _drawerList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.left_drawer);

        _drawer.SetDrawerShadow(Resource.Drawable.drawer_shadow_dark, (int)GravityFlags.Start);

        _drawerList.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,
            Resource.Layout.DrawerListItem, _planetTitles);
        _drawerList.ItemClick += (sender, args) => SelectItem(args.Position);


        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        //DrawerToggle is the animation that happens with the indicator next to the
        //ActionBar icon. You can choose not to use this.
        _drawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(this, _drawer,
                                                  Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer,
                                                  Resource.String.DrawerOpen,
                                                  Resource.String.DrawerClose);

        //You can alternatively use _drawer.DrawerClosed here
        _drawerToggle.DrawerClosed += delegate
        {
            ActionBar.Title = _title;
            InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };

        //You can alternatively use _drawer.DrawerOpened here
        _drawerToggle.DrawerOpened += delegate
        {
            ActionBar.Title = _drawerTitle;
            InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        };

        _drawer.SetDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);

        if (null == savedInstanceState)
            SelectItem(0);
    }

    private void SelectItem(int position)
    {
        var fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        var arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.PutInt(PlanetFragment.ArgPlanetNumber, position);
        fragment.Arguments = arguments;

        FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
            .Commit();

        _drawerList.SetItemChecked(position, true);
        ActionBar.Title = _title = _planetTitles[position];
        _drawer.CloseDrawer(_drawerList);
    }

    protected override void OnPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _drawerToggle.SyncState();
    }

    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        _drawerToggle.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.main, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public override bool OnPrepareOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        var drawerOpen = _drawer.IsDrawerOpen(Resource.Id.left_drawer);
        menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_websearch).SetVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        if (_drawerToggle.OnOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;

        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.action_websearch:
                {
                    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionWebSearch);
                    intent.PutExtra(SearchManager.Query, ActionBar.Title);

                    if ((intent.ResolveActivity(PackageManager)) != null)
                        StartActivity(intent);
                    else
                        Toast.MakeText(this, Resource.String.app_not_available, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    return true;
                }
            case Resource.Id.action_slidingpane:
                {
                    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SlidingPaneLayoutActivity));
                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                    StartActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my fragment file

```
public class PlanetFragment : DialogFragment
{
    public static string ArgPlanetNumber = "planet_number";
    ConnectDB db = new ConnectDB();


    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater p0, ViewGroup p1, Bundle p2)
    {

        var i = Arguments.GetInt(ArgPlanetNumber);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            var rootView = p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomePermainan, p1, false);
            return rootView;

        }
        else
        {
            var rootView = p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyProfile, p1, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my axml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cobaButton" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button4" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the `cobaButton` in your `fragment` layout like this:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Example_Fragment, container, false);
    var button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cobaButton);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android you can use [FindViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) to get a view by its id. As it's independent from the tpye of view, it will search through the viewtree for this element. So with `rootView.FindViewById(id)` you'll get the button.

So with the generic method this sums up to

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater p0, ViewGroup p1, Bundle p2)
{
    var i = Arguments.GetInt(ArgPlanetNumber);
    if (i == 0)
    {
        var rootView = p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomePermainan, p1, false);
        // I just assume the button is in HomePermainan
        var button = rootView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cobaButton);
        // Do whatever you want with this button like
        button.Click += (sender, args) => { Console.Write("Button clicked"); };
        return rootView;
    }
    else
    {
        return p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyProfile, p1, false);
    }
}
```